# Cassandra: High volume sensor data clarification

Tags: cassandra, time-series, nosql

We are considering transitioning our time series application from SQL Server to Cassandra, as the volume of data is becoming too large for SQL Server to handle. We can have up to 100 sensors working at the same time (sometimes for a whole year, sometimes shorter, but usually at least 50 of them simultaneously), and each of them is capable of transmitting up to 20 different measurements at up to 60 Hz (potentially 120 in the future).

Most online resources (e.g. [DataStax](http://academy.datastax.com)) recommend partitioning into "manageable partitions", which is presumably something below 1,000,000 rows (actually, something below say 50MB is probably the actual metric). So for 1 Hz reporting rates, partitioning each sensor quantity by a single week would produce `(7 * 24 * 60 * 60) = 604,800` measurements per partition:

```
CREATE TABLE measurements (
    sensor_id       TEXT,
    quantity        TEXT,
    start_of_week   TIMESTAMP,
    offset_seconds  INT,        -- offset from week start (0..604799)
    value           FLOAT,
    PRIMARY KEY ((sensor_id, quantity, start_of_week), offset_seconds)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (offset_seconds DESC)
```

So, naturally, for **60 Hz** reporting rates I might partition **by hour** to keep it simple and get `(60 * 60 * 60) = 216,000` measurements per partition. Or several hours, of course.

However, I have a couple of uncertainties on how this will work in practice.

Until now, we had a rather denormalized SQL Server database, where we would put all 20 values from a single sensor in a single row, and the server was able to keep up (albeit with CPU constantly being ~30%) for up to 50 devices (that's basically 3,000 rows per second, and we presume SQL Server can max at about 10,000 rows/s). Needless to say, this cannot scale at all if new quantities are added per device, while at the same time lots of space is wasted for devices which report less than 20 quantities.

However, with the C* approach above, it seems the number of key-value pairs stored per second (presuming 100 sensors, 20 measurements, 60 Hz) will be **120,000 per second**.

1. Is it possible to achieve this with the "base" 3 node setup? How many Cassandra nodes are needed in practice, for such insertion rates?
2. Would moving all sub-second (60 Hz) values for a single quantity into a single **blob** improve performance? This would mean total insertion rate would be 2,000 *blobs*, which seems much more manageable (and even a blob size of 240 bytes for 60 float32 values doesn't seem that huge).

Most of the time the data will be displayed from a different table which holds pre-calculated min/max/average aggregates (the user can create a full-resolution range query at any time, but for smaller ranges), so our emphasis is to **maximize write throughput**. If you believe any other schema might provide better throughput (I don't have a clue, perhaps multiple tables/some other partitioning/clustering strategies), please suggest. We are even open to switching to a different NoSQL database, if it can fit our requirements better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to achieve this with the "base" 3 node setup? How many Cassandra nodes are needed in practice, for such insertion rates?

120,000 per second with a 3 node cluster is certainly possible but it depends a lot on your hardware. I would expect 20k-30k/sec with normal instances. A rule of thumb I stick with is 4k/sec/core but its very hardware/load dependent.

> Would moving all sub-second (60 Hz) values for a single quantity into a single blob improve performance? This would mean total insertion rate would be 2,000 blobs, which seems much more manageable (and even a blob size of 240 bytes for 60 float32 values doesn't seem that huge).

Yes it will help throughput.

Some notes:

Make sure with this kind of load your client is performing your queries efficiently or you may see bottle necks there. Making inserts async and applying back pressure based on in flight requests is a good idea. There is batching, but its only efficient if all the writes go into same partition. So if you have 60 readings for the second and are inserting them all into the same partition it will be faster to do an **unlogged** batch. Logged batches will be massively slower. There is a point that this ends up becoming worse for performance though but the number is different for different workloads so may want to play with it.

I would recommend Timed Window Compaction Strategy (TWCS) for this workload.

In the 2.x versions 100mb per partition is a good limit to try to stay under. In later 3.x releases and 4.x future releases you are much safer going higher yet (ie gb). That said partitions are still the lowest level so if they get too large it can still lead to hot spots, and it makes things like repairs much less efficient. Keep eye on the max/mean table partition size in monitoring.

With `offset_seconds` that is actually better to be a full timestamp. When you do a read it checks the min/max clustering keys vs whats queried to determine which sstable to read. Each sstable stores its min/max clustering key to optimize time series like this. If you have TWCS and you are querying a range of time it will be able to narrow down the sstables to just the relevant ones. Otherwise it will likely include a lot of them since the offsets will reset in every bucket and have overlaps. The bloom filter should catch some of the ones with different partition keys but it will have false positives and requires checking the bloom filters on all the sstables (this is done after picking from min/max and is far from free). It may seem a bit wasteful for space but it will improve reads a lot.

Comment: Thanks! One clarification though: 1) does this mean that unlogged batches skip the commit (transaction) log completely? It seems like batches are [recommended against](https://medium.com/@foundev/cassandra-batch-loading-without-the-batch-keyword-40f00e35e23e) by certain people for the reasons you mentioned yourself, but I don't want to lose atomicity/durability. And 2) do you know of some practical values on C* throughput **in MB**? Since with 240B blobs, insertion rate turns out to be 2000 inserts/s, but it's obviously different from as inserting 20B rows.

Comment: (one answer is obviously "why don't you profile it and see for yourself", but  just to have some rough ideas about what to expect - I don't want to suggest investing in a setup which cannot possibly work for our use case)

Comment: unlogged batches still goes through normal thing but it skips the paxos stuff and the double writing that logged batches go through. It is recommended against (included by me) when you have multiple partitions since it requires the coordinator to do a lot of work and increases chances of it failing since it touches so many nodes. If all the rows of the batch are in same partition though it saves a round trip and some overhead. http://christopher-batey.blogspot.com/2015/02/cassandra-anti-pattern-misuse-of.html has good explanation on how it can be good too.

Comment: I cant really give guidance on a rule of thumb for mb/sec. That is gonna depend a bit on disks. I do highly recommend using cassandra-stress to test this out vs own benchmarking though, you will find it much easier to focus on C* vs client. Also note I edited above to include a note on your clustering index.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the tips, including the clustering tip, until now I didn't realize how sstables actually store data (I had a feeling that partition key + clustering key behave like a composite key for the sstable). It would be cool if this could be mentioned in DataStax examples for data modeling (sensors use case).